# Where to copy "initialization patameter file" using oracle database?

Tags: java, database, oracle

I'm compltely new in `Oracle database` now I'm trying to copy a `intilization parameter` file from this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/create005.htm#ADMIN11099). But Question is: Where to save `init.ora` file in which directory?.. please help?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the OS.

For Unix/Linux, by default it is `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs`

For Windows,

Default location for spfile in a windows platform is here: 
`%ORACLE_HOME%\database\spfile%ORACLE_SID%.ora`

For a pfile, path is the same:
`%ORACLE_HOME%\database\init%ORACLE_SID%.ora`

Answer (score 0):

as per oracle flexible architecture we put pfile in
$ORACLE_BASE/admin/database_name/pfile/

and spfile is present in 
$ORACLE_HOME/dbs